# Cant add second ng-controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am pretty new in angular/js development so now i stacked with this.

When I add **ng-controller="HeaderController"** to my HTML code it cant load Angular. If you remove this everything is fine. Why that happened? Thanks for any help and sorry for bad English :)

**Code:**

```js
(function() {
 var app = angular.module ('FunStuff',[]);

 app.controller ('TextController',['$scope',function($scope){
  $scope.stuff = [];
  $scope.add = function(){
    $scope.stuff.push ($scope.name);
  }
 }]);
 app.controller ('HeaderController'['$scope',function($scope){
  $scope.textClass = '';
  $scope.changeClrClss = function(name){
   $scope.ClrClss = name;
  }
 }]);
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app ="FunStuff">

<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.32/angular.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <title>LEARN JS</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body >

 <header  ng-class = "ColorClass" ng-controller="HeaderController">
  <h1>$~/Path_To_Js/</h1>
  <button class="changeColorBtn" ng-click="changeColorClass('white')">
   ChangeColorButton
  </button>
 </header>

 <div class="wrapper" >
  <article ng-controller = "TextController">
   <p>There will be some information</p>
   <form ng-submit="add()">
    <input ng-model="name"><button>Add</button>
   </form>
   <ul class="buttons" ng-repeat= "n in stuff track by $index">
    <li>{{n}}</li>
   </ul>
  </article>
 </div>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your error says, You are missing **`,`**  after the header controller,

```
app.controller ('HeaderController',['$scope',function($scope){
        $scope.textClass = '';
        $scope.changeClrClss = function(name){
            $scope.ClrClss = name;
        }
    }]);
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module ('FunStuff',[]);

 app.controller ('TextController',['$scope',function($scope){
  $scope.stuff = [];
  $scope.add = function(){
    $scope.stuff.push ($scope.name);
  }
 }]);
 app.controller ('HeaderController',['$scope',function($scope){
  $scope.textClass = '';
  $scope.changeClrClss = function(name){
   $scope.ClrClss = name;
  }
 }]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app ="FunStuff">

<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.32/angular.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <title>LEARN JS</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body >

 <header  ng-class = "ColorClass" ng-controller="HeaderController">
  <h1>$~/Path_To_Js/</h1>
  <button class="changeColorBtn" ng-click="changeColorClass('white')">
   ChangeColorButton
  </button>
 </header>

 <div class="wrapper" >
  <article ng-controller = "TextController">
   <p>There will be some information</p>
   <form ng-submit="add()">
    <input ng-model="name"><button>Add</button>
   </form>
   <ul class="buttons" ng-repeat= "n in stuff track by $index">
    <li>{{n}}</li>
   </ul>
  </article>
 </div>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module ('FunStuff',[]);

    app.controller ('TextController',['$scope',function($scope){
        $scope.stuff = [];
        $scope.add = function(){
                $scope.stuff.push ($scope.name);
        }
    }]);
    app.controller ('HeaderController',['$scope',function($scope){
                                    //^^ missing comma here
        $scope.textClass = '';
        $scope.changeClrClss = function(name){
            $scope.ClrClss = name;
        }
    }]);
})();
```